# Sort objects in array based on property and its sort order

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

I need to sort an object array based on the status in Angular 16+. My status order should be:

```
[N-Op, Used, Unknown, Op]
```

Sample data:

```
const stockList = [
    {
      'heading': 'SK',
      'status': 'N-Op',
    },
    {
      'heading': 'SKU',
      'status': 'Op',
    },
    {
      'heading': 'Uniliver',
      'status': 'Op',
    },
    {
      'heading': 'Bugati',
      'status': 'Unknown',
    },
    {
      'heading': 'Bugati',
      'status': 'N-Op',
    },
  ];
```

How could I achieve the expected result as below?

```
const stockList = [
    {
      'heading': 'SK',
      'status': 'N-Op',
    },
    {
      'heading': 'Bugati',
      'status': 'N-Op',
    },
    {
      'heading': 'Bugati',
      'status': 'Unknown',
    },
    {
      'heading': 'SKU',
      'status': 'Op',
    },
    {
      'heading': 'Uniliver',
      'status': 'Op',
    }
  ];
```

Comment: It seems your data in the expected result is different for the `status` value compared to the provided data. So it is not just sorting but value transforming as well?

Comment: @YongShun updated! thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and defining the custom logic to compare the index from the `sortOrder` array.

Assume that all values of `status` existed in `sortOrder` array.

```
const sortOrder = ["N-Op", "Used", "Unknown", "Op"];

let sortedStockList  = stockList.sort((a, b) => {
    let xIndex = sortOrder.indexOf(a.status);
    let yIndex = sortOrder.indexOf(b.status);

    if (xIndex < yIndex)
        return -1;
    else if (xIndex > yIndex)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
});
```

(Optional) If you want the sort followed by `heading`, you can replace `return 0;` with

```
return a.heading.localeCompare(b.heading);
```

Comment: how can I do the sort with heading in ascending after the sort with status? I used your a.heading.localeCompare(b.heading); line in again a separate sort function.

Comment: Hi, please check my answer, the **(Optional)** part. You no need another sort function, you can do it within the same method by replacing the `return 0;`.